# How can I give a named squid egg to a player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am running Minecraft 1.9 and I am trying to give the player a squid egg with a custom name of "Create Script".

This is the command I have used:

```
/give chrisdude011 minecraft:spawn_egg 1 94 {EntityTag:{id:"Squid",CustomName:"Create Script",ench:[]}}
```

However, this only gives me the spawn squid egg with nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

The squid is indeed spawned with the specified custom name. If you are talking about the enchantment overlay (via `ench:[]`), you specified it in the wrong depth, causing it to be potential entity data instead of item data.

As well, spawn eggs do not use Damage values anymore, thus a value of 94 is invalid and will default back to 0.

Fixed command, moving `ench:[]` to the root of the `tag` tag:

```
/give chrisdude011 minecraft:spawn_egg 1 0 {ench:[],EntityTag:{id:"Squid",CustomName:"Create Script"}}
```

For the display name of the item itself, you use the `Name` string inside the `display` compound. Example:

```
/give chrisdude011 minecraft:stone 1 0 {display:{Name:"Create Script"}}
```

With your spawn egg:

```
/give chrisdude011 minecraft:spawn_egg 1 0 {ench:[],display:{Name:"Create Script"},EntityTag:{id:"Squid",CustomName:"Create Script"}}
```

Comment: I have tried this but the name stays the same i.i Spawn Squid

Comment: @chrisdude011 I see, in that case you use the `Name` string inside the `display` compound of the item format. I've updated the answer to include this.